# NetworkManager constantly prompts for admin password

Tags: network-manager, 19.10, policykit

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.
NetworkManager constantly asks for the admin password with "System policy prevents wi-fi scans"
I've seen online instructions for how to disable this with polkit, but nothing seems to work. What is the *current* way to set polkit rules? I'm also prompted when shutting down.

Comment: Anyone else with this problem: It was caused by either installing chrome-remote-desktop or xrdp in general; although, I would suspect chrome-remote-desktop since it's such a... non-idiomatic package on Ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to set polkit rules is by creating a pkla file, as opposed to editing the policy files in /usr (which get overwritten on updates)

Here is a step by step process to allow stop those annoying wifi-scan password prompts:

1. In terminal, run `sudo su -`
2. `cd /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d`
3. `nano 10-network-manager.pkla`

Then paste in the following:

```
[Allow wi-fi scans for all users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

4. Save and exit using `CTRL+X` and `y`
5. `service network-manager restart`

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 the policies were all fixed, I still have no idea why they became so draconian or how to revert all policies to defaults. Anyway, I'm almost certain I tried both this and the /usr approach and nothing worked; behaviour never changed, but since I can't or don't want to test this right now I'll give you the gold as this makes sense to me

Comment: i completely agree that new pplicies are too restrictive. this worked for me, hope it works for you as well

Comment: I couldn't restart this service on Ubuntu 20.10. `Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.`
But it's working without restart

Comment: worked on raspberry pi os Bookworn

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I am encountering it on automated workstations, systems running 20.04 LTS, and answers online are sparse or misleading.

See the following file `cat /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/60-network-manager.rules`  which in 20.04 shows

```
  if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system" &&
    subject.local && subject.active && 
    (subject.isInGroup ("sudo") || subject.isInGroup ("netdev"))) {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});
```

It is clear from this that your user must be a member of the group `sudo` or `netdev`.

The original install user is a member
of sudo typically, but other users are not.  You should add them to the `netdev` group (if `sudo` is not appropriate, as it is not in my employee workstation context).